# How to use Redux with Reactjs - this basic d3.js chart as an example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, redux

I am new to Reactjs - mostly though with incorporating Redux. I am keen to learn how to improve the code base below to use Redux - so get to understand what is wrong with this current example and how to clean it up fully - with the addition of Redux - and an explanation as to why to use Redux and its main purpose.

So here is some test json data for the pie chart

```
var data = [{
                    "label": "Belleville Brewing Company",
                    "value": 1233
                  }, {
                    "label": "Kew Brewery",
                    "value": 345
                  }, {
                    "label": "Laines Brewery (Four Thieves)",
                    "value": 6786
                  }, {
                    "label": "Sultan Brewery",
                    "value": 678
                  }, {
                    "label": "The Wimbledon Brewery Company Limited",
                    "value": 45
                  }];
```

//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

var $ = require("jquery");

import PieChart from './modules/7_pieChart/PieChart';   


var MultipleComponents = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        username: '',
        lastGistUrl: '',
        rawData: '',
        config: ''
      };
    },

    componentDidMount: function () {


      var config = [];

        this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
          var lastGist = result[0];
          this.setState({
            username: lastGist.owner.login,
            lastGistUrl: lastGist.html_url,
            rawData: lastGist,
            config: config
          });
        }.bind(this));
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
      this.serverRequest.abort();
    },


    getLayers: function(data){
      var items = [];
      var j = 0;


      items.push(  <PieChart 
                      key="5"
                      width="350" 
                      height="350" 
                      radius="200" 
                      innerradius="120" 
                      serviceApi=""/> );

      return items;      
    },


    render: function () {
       var config = this.state.config;

       console.log("config", config);

       return (
            <div className="apps">
                {this.getLayers(config[0])}
            </div>
        );
    }
});




ReactDOM.render(
    <MultipleComponents source="https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists" />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

//pie chart js

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    var $ = require("jquery");
    var d3 = require("d3");
    import './PieChart.css';

    class PieChart extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));

            var data = [{
                "label": "Belleville Brewing Company",
                "value": 1233
              }, {
                "label": "Kew Brewery",
                "value": 345
              }, {
                "label": "Laines Brewery (Four Thieves)",
                "value": 6786
              }, {
                "label": "Sultan Brewery",
                "value": 678
              }, {
                "label": "The Wimbledon Brewery Company Limited",
                "value": 45
              }];


            var w = $this.data("width");
            var h = $this.data("height");
            var ir = $this.data("innerradius");
            var r = $this.data("radius");

            function colores_google(n) {
                var colores_g = ["#f7b363", "#448875", "#c12f39", "#2b2d39", "#f8dd2f"];
                //var colores_g = ["#47abd5", "#005a70", "#f5a0a3", "#ff7276", "#a9a19c", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"];
                return colores_g[n % colores_g.length];
            }

            var radius = Math.min(w, h) / 3;


            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius - 10)
                .innerRadius(0);

            var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius - r)
                .innerRadius(radius - ir);    

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .sort(null)
                .value(function(d) { return d.value; });


            var chart = d3.select($this[0]).append("svg:svg")
                            .attr("class", "chart")
                            .attr("width", w - (w/3))
                            .attr("height", h)
                                .append("svg:g")
                                .attr("class", "piechart")
                                .attr("transform", "translate(20,"+h/3+")");

            var path_group = chart.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "path_group")
                .attr("transform", "translate(90," + ((h / 4) - 20) + ")");


            var padding = 45;
            var legendPaddingTop = 30;
            var legend = d3.select($this[0]).append("svg:svg")
                .attr("class", "legend")
                .attr("width", w/2)
                .attr("height", h)
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "legendsection")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((w/4) + padding) + "," + legendPaddingTop + ")");    


            var label_group = legend.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "label_group")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-(w / 3) + 20) + "," + 0 + ")");

            var legend_group = legend.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "legend_group")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (-(w / 3) - 100) + "," + 0 + ")");


            var g = path_group.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(pie(data))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

            g.append("path")
                .attr("d", arc)
                .style("fill", function(d, i) { 
                    return colores_google(i);
                });


            var legendHeight = legendPaddingTop;
            var ySpace = 18;
            var labelPadding = 3;

            //draw labels                   
            var labels = label_group.selectAll("text.labels")
                .data(data);

            labels.enter().append("svg:text")
                .attr("class", "labels")
                .attr("dy", function(d, i) {                  
                    legendHeight+=ySpace;   
                  return (ySpace * i) + labelPadding;
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
                  return "start";
                })
                .text(function(d) {
                  return d.label;
                });

            labels.exit().remove();
            //draw labels


            //draw legend
            var legend = legend_group.selectAll("circle").data(data);

            legend.enter().append("svg:circle")
                .attr("cx", 100)
                .attr("cy", function(d, i) {
                  return ySpace * i;
                })
                .attr("r", 7)
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", 18)
                .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                  return colores_google(i);
                });

            legend.exit().remove();
            //draw legend

            //reset legend height
            //console.log("optimum height for legend", legendHeight);
            $this.find('.legend').attr("height", legendHeight);

            function type(d) {
              d.value = +d.value;
              return d;
            }

        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="piechart" data-role="piechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height} data-radius={this.props.radius}  data-innerradius={this.props.innerradius}
                    data-data={this.props.data}>
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    export default PieChart;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll address several issues with the code you posted. The purpose here is to provide a guide without explaining in depth each part.

### Redux

[Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) (and [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)) is there to manage the state of your application. It provides a central store which should hold all the data needed to render your app and a [mechanism](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to update components when the state of the store changes.

The functional flow in your case would be:

1. container mounts
2. it issues an API call via AJAX
3. when call returns [dispatch](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#dispatch) an [action](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html), e.g. `dataReceived`*
4. a [reducer](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) handles the action by updating the store
5. your container/component that should be [connected](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) is updated with the new data from the store via its props
6. component re-renders with new data

[* you usually will want to track the request's progress as well so you will dispatch and action before you perform the request (e.g. `dataRequested`) and perhaps `dataRequestFailed` if an error occurs ]

### jQuery

You don't need it.

React should be used to pass props to child components and to update the DOM.

Why are you passing the width and height props via the DOM instead of accessing them directly via `this.props` in your rendering code?

Ajax requests can be made with many different libraries that do just that.

### D3

There are a [few](https://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2016/06/03/d3-and-react-3-ways/) approaches on how to integrate D3 with React. 
You can either let D3 do all the rendering or use a faux-DOM and render it with React.

The code you posted renders using D3, but it does so only in the `componentDidMount` method. You should hook also to the `componentDidUpdate` method so that you can pass updated props to D3. [Here](http://nicolashery.com/integrating-d3js-visualizations-in-a-react-app/) is a nice writeup on how this can be achieved.

### Minimal POC

I've added a simple demonstration of the flow I've described above

*Notes*

`connect` is used to create a component which is subscribed to changes in the store and will automatically update when the store changes.

`mapStateToProps` defines which properties of the store should be passed to the container.

`mapDispatchToProps` bind actions to the `dispatch` method allowing for easy usage inside the container via `this.props.<action_name>`.

The reducer is written using a switch statement to illustrate the fact that reducers can handle more than 1 action.

```js
// reducers.js
const reducer = (state = {data: []}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'DATA_RECEIVED':
     return {...state, data: [...state.data, action.payload] }
   }
  return state;
}

// store.js
const store = Redux.createStore(reducer)

// actions.js
function dataReceived(payload) {
  console.log('dataReceived action: ', payload);
  return {
    type: 'DATA_RECEIVED',
    payload,
  }
}

// pie_chart.js
class PieChart extends React.Component {
  
  _update() {
    const svg = d3.select(this.node).select('svg')
      .attr('width', this.props.width)
      .attr('height', this.props.height)
    
    const y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(this.props.data)
      .rangePoints([20, this.props.height - 10])
    
    const textItems = svg.selectAll('text').data(this.props.data)
    
    textItems.enter().append('text').text(d => d)
    
    textItems.transition().attr('y', (d, i) => y(d))
    
    textItems.exit().remove()
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const svg = d3.select(this.node)
      .append('svg')
      
    this._update()
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._update()
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container" ref={node => this.node = node}/>
    )
  }
}

// chart_container.js
function mapStateToProps(state) { 
  return { data: state.data }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dataReceived: Redux.bindActionCreators(dataReceived, dispatch),
  }
}

const ChartContainer = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(class ChartContainer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let items = 3
    
    const active = setInterval(() => {     // simulate API call
      this.props.dataReceived('data item ' + items);
      if (items < 1) { 
        clearInterval(active)
      }
      items -= 1
      
    }, 3000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.props.data.length > 0 ? 
      <PieChart width={100} height={100} data={this.props.data} /> :
      <div>no data yet</div>
      
    )
  }
})

// app.js
ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
    <ChartContainer />
  </ReactRedux.Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.4/react-redux.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Is there way of showing a demo of this redux part? Mock how the api service would work or show where the dummy json data would be returned?

Comment: Is there some mock code that could show a transition towards using redux with the pie chart example? @thedude

Comment: Thank you @thedude - you able to explain a little what is going on here. So ChartContainer gets invoked and this is where it makes a connection to the reactredux - so this is like querying the store? Now mapDispatchToProps looks like a bridge sending a request and receiving a request? mapStateToProps populates the store with the data? Now the store - is like an object that contains the current data? --  the reducer can received different types of data - why is in a case? So I am a bit confused on the purpose of the action. Now you place the api call in the compntdidmount which invokes aciton

Comment: @TheOldCounty I've added some notes, but I strongly suggest you take a look at the [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html)

Comment: "The reducer is written using a switch statement to illustrate the fact that reducers can handle more than 1 action." -- what other action could a reducer take on -- in this case its a getdata -- is it a case that you could push different api calls or different data sets? Or I suppose this is where you could create master/slave relationships with other chart components? If you had a store in the index that acts as a master controller?

Comment: other actions can be `removeData`, `dataRequestFailed` etc.

Comment: Is see - so if dataRequestfailed push dummy/empty data into the chart and/or show a message. How close is this example to production ready?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142383/discussion-between-thedude-and-the-old-county).

Comment: I need your assistance on a register form -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942891/reactjs-redux-storing-data-from-a-form-submission